# Worpdress theme development

Tags: wordpress-theming

I would like to develop a theme starting from underscores.me The goal is to have a theme combined with elementor, with an integrated control panel to change some features, an autoinstaller, importer demo one click, etc. I'm trying to process underscores. I need a very light theme. Could someone advise me if starting from underscores.me is the right choice. In your opinion, even with a few changes, can the theme be reused to sell it on themeforest by uploading customized demos? I wanted to know if someone think it's the right choice, or can suggest me a better starter theme to develop (knowing that I'm not a senior developer, i can just add some feature to the code or eliminate others).
many thanks Guys, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

underscore.me is my preferred starter theme, in my opinion is a really good choice. Is really light, have just what you need to create your own theme, nothing superfluous.

You said that you're not senior, I suggest you to avoid starter theme with useless things that contribuite to complicate the development.

With _.me I also suggest you to try ACF (andvanced custom field) to develop your options panel: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/

In themeforest redux is often used https://redux.io/ to develop the options, still good: is free, not so simple as ACF but not too difficult.

To sell in theme forest you need a lot of customization and have to write clean code, choose the right plugin to pack together with theme and pay attention to license restriction.